# Calculating dx In BCE Backpropagation With Batches

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, backpropagation

I am trying to backpropagate from scratch using batches and I am having issues calculating dx. First, I would like to start by defining variables to avoid confusion:

```
a - The activation value calculated by passing z through an activation function

z - The value before the activation function of the layer

x - The inputs into the layer

w - The weights that connect the inputs to the output nodes

da - The derivative of a

dz - The derivative of z

dx - The derivative of x
```

I know that this is the derivative of x:

```
dx = w.T*dz
Note: * means dot and .T means transpose
```

Now let me introduce the problem. Say I have a neural network with 2 inputs, 3 output nodes, and a batch size of 5. How would I go about computing dx? In this case, the weights would be of shape (z, x) or (3, 2) before transposing and dz would be of shape (z, batches) or (3, 5). If I were to use the formula above, I would get a shape of (x, batches) or (2, 5). Would I take the sum with respect to the last dimension after using the formula above to get dx (resulting in a shape of (2, 1))? Below is a representation of the dot product using made-up values:

```
     w.T          *          dz            =        dx
                      [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[[1,  0.5, 1],    *    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],    =   [[2.5,  5,  7.5,  10,  12.5],
 [-1, -1,  -0.5]       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]         [-2.5, -5, -7.5, -10, -12.5]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did everything correctly. X always needs to have the same dimensions as dX in backpropagation. If X was an intermediate outcome of shape (2,5), then the gradient also has the shape (2,5). In this way you can update the matrix X. Now in your case matrix X is the input matrix, which you will never update. You only need to update W.

If X was the result of a hidden layer, your calculation of the backpropagated gradient is correct.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I was a little worried I was calculating it wrong due to the shapes having to match. Initially, I thought calculating dx was using for the backward pass, not to update x, but to continue to backward pass to the previous layer. I realize I don't need dx after all and only dw and db. Calculating dx was still good practice though.